# Unpinning a object after a timeOut in Parse Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, local-storage

I am using Parse LocalStore for storing the objects locally.

I am pinning all the objects in the local store and fetching from local store.

The problem i have is , when the data changes in parse it is not getting reflected in my app, because i am fetching all the queries from local store.

How can i approach this problem. Is there any way we can set expiry time for pinned objects in local store so that when the time is expired the data is unpinned from local store and gets new data from parse.

Answer (score 0):

You can always implement a refresh button (or pull-down to refresh, if using listview/recyclerview and when activated, it should clear your existing objects while adding the latest-retrieved objects from Parse.

Comment: i have to do it automatically. Without user intervention